# Conversion of string to LocalDateTime in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

How to convert a string "23:00" to LocalDateTime in Java 8?
This doesn't seems to be working,

```
LocalDateTime dateTime1 = LocalDateTime.parse("23:00", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm"));
```

This is the exception that is thrown,

```
java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 23:00 of type java.time.format.Parsed
```

Comment: Better provide some comment and then downvote.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You only pass time information to the parser, and it needs to create a LocalDateTime. The parser can't guess which Date part you want for the LocateDateTime.

Use

```
LocalDateTime time = 
    LocalTime.parse("23:00", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm"))
        .atDate(LocalDate.now());
```

for example, if you want **today** at 23:00.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. As from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html):

> LocalDate stores a date without a time. This stores a date like '2010-12-03' and could be used to store a birthday.
>
> LocalTime stores a time without a date. This stores a time like '11:30' and could be used to store an opening or closing time.
>
> LocalDateTime stores a date and time. This stores a date-time like '2010-12-03T11:30'.

So, if you want to do that, you'll need to create a LocalTime instead. If you really need a `LocalDateTime`, use this instead: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#of-java.time.LocalDate-java.time.LocalTime-